# How can I turn off notification sounds in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: notifications, system-sounds, microsoft-teams

Every time I get a notification banner I also get a sound. The banner is fine, the sound is not.

[This support article of Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/six-things-to-know-about-notifications-abb62c60-3d15-4968-b86a-42fea9c22cf4) states:

> To choose if a sound plays with each new notification, select your profile picture at the top right corner of Teams, then Settings > Notifications > toggle off/on.

[image: notification sound toggle in teams]

However on my Teams versions `1.3.00.12058 (64-bit)` I don't have that toggle:

[image]

How do I turn off sounds for every notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1.4.00.26376

In version `1.4.00.26376 (64-bit)` the toggle has re-appeared under the notifications settings under the *Appearance and sound* section:

[image: Screenshot highlighting the settings location in version 1.4.00.26376]

#### 1.3.00.12058

In version `1.3.00.12058 (64-bit)` the toggle has moved to the *Other* section as a drop down menu (third option from the top):

[image: Screenshot highlighting the settings location in version 1.3.00.12058]

Comment: The problem is, that the same switch is used for audio call but I'd rather miss calls than hear the annoying chat message noise all the time...